# Extract values from a xml file

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a .yml file from which i have to extract data

i converted the file to xml using below code but now not getting how to extract the data from it.

i thought of using Select-xml so converted to xml

```
$Xml = "D:\DIR_LIST.yml"
$Cont=@()
$Cont = Get-Content -Path $Xml

$Cont | ConvertTo-Xml -As String | Out-File "D:\newxml.xml"
```

below is the xml data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Objects>
  <Object Type="System.String">&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">&lt;tree&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">  &lt;directory name="."&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">    &lt;file name="DIR_LIST.txt" size="14"&gt;&lt;/file&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">    &lt;file name="DIR_LIST.yml" size="0"&gt;&lt;/file&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">    &lt;file name="File_Details.sh" size="252"&gt;&lt;/file&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">    &lt;directory name="test1" size="4096"&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">      &lt;directory name="sub1" size="4096"&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">        &lt;directory name="sub2" size="4096"&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">        &lt;/directory&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">      &lt;/directory&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">    &lt;/directory&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">    &lt;directory name="test2" size="4096"&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">    &lt;/directory&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">  &lt;/directory&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">  &lt;report&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">    &lt;directories&gt;4&lt;/directories&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">    &lt;files&gt;3&lt;/files&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">  &lt;/report&gt;</Object>
  <Object Type="System.String">&lt;/tree&gt;</Object>
</Objects>
```

Looking to extract the directory name= values

Please let me know how to proceed or approach i am doing is wrong.

Comment: [1] why use `-As String` instead of the default `-As Document`? [2] have you tried using the `-NoTypeInformation` parameter yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file was not converted correctly, however you can use below script, and then do some text modifications.

```
$xmlpath = 'path\to\xml'
[xml]$xmldoc = Get-Content -Path $xmlpath
$objects = $xmldoc.Objects.Object
$objects | Select-Object -Property '#text' | where {$_ -match 'directory name'}
```